# Working on several independent folders on a GIT repo

Tags: git

I have a GIT repo with some folders, where a folder is meant for separate project.
So, each folder is completely independent from the others and I'd like to stay on the same repo, but at the same time working safely on each folder.

As far as I know, the best way to achieve this is to create a local copy for each folder and then push each folder on a specific branch.
If this is correct, it's unclear to me how can I track only that folder in local, since when I go for a pull it takes everything.

Comment: If they're independent projects, why are they in one repo?

Comment: You have to create one branch per folder and don't forget to checkout to the correct branch when doing modifications

Comment: @jonrsharpe He didn't said that those folders where independent projects. You could imagine an application where you have a client side, a gateway and an IoT network. This could lead in 3 folders that have nothing to do with each other but they are still from the same project. Or just imagine a course where you have different assignments during the year, you maybe don't want to create a new repo for each assignment

Comment: @desmaxi *"a folder is meant for separate project"*... And in those examples I still wouldn't make those things different branches.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oups, my bad. But my second example (course assignments) is still a correct use case. Nope I wouldn't too but if he really want's that's how I would do it.

Comment: @desmaxi I would **definitely** want to create a new repo for each assignment (and I would create a meta repo with an installer to pull and display all assignments of the year if needed). Back to the question: even if those folders were holding 'modules' needed for the same 'project', the keyword here is `independant` => seperate repos without any hesitation.